# How to convert octal into binary in Swift 4+

Tags: swift

I am trying to convert octal number into binary number in my current project. I cant seem to find a solution to convert octal number into binary format in Swift  language.

Ive already tried converting it from octal to decimal then, convert it to decimal to binary, but the answer is different even though the decimal to binary process is working perfect. So i think the fault is in the octal conversions.

This is my code for getting the octal number:

```
let octy = octTextfield.text!
let octalInt = Int(octy, radix: 0o10) // converts the string input to octal
```

Comment: Your octal conversion looks correct. Note that you might need to drop your octal string prefix "0o" if present when converting it to Integer

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the `String` into a number then convert the given number into it's binary representation:

```swift
func octalToBinary(number: String) -> String? {
    guard let tmp = Int(number, radix: 8) else {
        return nil
    }

    return String(tmp, radix: 2)
}

octalToBinary(number: "123") // "1010011"
```

Comment: you mean `guard let tmp = Int(number, radix: 8)`

Comment: My bad, copy pasted mistake :x